# Display time in GUI

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I am working on a personal project very simple but this is part of a bigger project. Any help is appreciated. This is my code the and the output is wrong, when I run it, it displays one big window and one separate small window displaying the time. The right way should be displaying time in the big frame in a JLabel.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
//package Employees;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class DateShowAPII extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form DateShowAPI
 */
public DateShowAPII() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    JLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel2.setText("Time");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(104, 104, 104)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(JLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(179, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,    layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(139, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(JLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGap(132, 132, 132))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    JLabel l = new JLabel(date);

    frame.getContentPane().add(l);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new DateShowAPII().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel JLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: "This is my code the and the output is wrong, when I run it, it displays one big window and one separate small window displaying the time. The right way should be displaying time in the big frame in a JLabel."  Read what he wrote.

Comment: QUESTION: It is not displaying the time in big FRAME so I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateShowAPII` is a frame (that's the big one) and in main, you create another one (and pack it) -- that's the small one with the time.

Instead, don't create another frame and add the JLabel to the new `DateShowAPII` you created.

Answer (score 2):

1) you declared two `JFrames`

> DateShowAPII extends javax.swing.JFrame

and

> JFrame frame = new JFrame();

looks like as with the same contents

2) use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and from [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) fire `JLabel#setText(date)`

3) don't use resersed Java method names as variable or Class name, meaning

```
JLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
```

rename to

```
myJLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
```